# Splitting a string with square braquets

Tags: java, string, split

Similar asked thread but I'm not looking for the same thing as those already posted.

Say I have a String "HELLOWORLDAH".

And I want it formated that way :

[HEL] [LOW] [ORL] [DAH].

The split() method seems to only work on splitting string which already have delimter. I'm looking to add delimiters and separate the strings by three.

Anyway to do this? I understand Regex somewhat.

Comment: Java. Currently I use         a = Arrays.toString(a.split("(?<=\\G.{3})"));, but it return [123, 456] instead of [123] [456]. I don't know if what I'm asking if possible.

Comment: can you clarify something? You need an array of arrays (or characters, each being 3 characters long) or do you need a String with brackets every three characters?

Answer (score 1):

The splitting already works. Now use [String.join()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)):

```
System.out.println("["+
    String.join("] [", "HELLOWORLDAH".split("(?<=\\G.{3})"))
+"]");
```

and you get `"[HEL] [LOW] [ORL] [DAH]"`.

Comment: PS: Simplest way to try is to start jshell and paste the code block.

Comment: Unnecessary detour `split`, followed by `join`. You can achieve the same via `"[" + "HELLOWORLDAH".replaceAll("(?<=\\G.{3})(?=.)", "] [") + "]"` and when the spaces are not important, the even simpler `"HELLOWORLDAH".replaceAll(".{1,3}", "[$0]")` would do.